# Chmod 777 on bind volume not working with in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to change my bind volume permissions with in docker file. I am mounting my container volume /sharedpath to a shared fs. And when i enter the container and then give chmod -R 777 /sharedpath everything seems working fine. But if I try the same command with in docker file and run the container, the permissions doesn't reflect.
For a normal folder with in container this works fine. Only to volume mount folder this happens. Is there any workaround i can do here?

Comment: Do not _ever_ use 777 as a permission set. It allows even completely unrelated users like `nobody` to write to your data!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah I totally get that. Since I am in building phase of my service i am trying with full permissions.